# One parameter group of elements of a banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a complex Banach algebra with identity $1_A$. Suppose we have a continuous one parameter group of elements of $A$, i.e. a continuous map $U:\mathbb R\to A$ such that:

- $U(0)=1_A$
- $U(t+s)=U(t)U(s)$ for all $t,s\in\mathbb R$

Is it true that there exists some $x\in A$ such that $U(t)=e^{tx}$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$?

It's not hard to prove that the claim is equivalent to the differentiability of $U$ at 0, i.e. to the existence of the limit $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{U(t)-1_A}{t}$, in which case $x$ is equal to the limit. I tried to come up with some counterexamples but always ended up constructing $U$ in such a way that it is not continuous.

Comment: Consider the algebra of bounded operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R}).$ The family $(U_tf)(x)=f(x+t)$ forms a continuous group of unitary operators. But the generator is an unbounded operator.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, your example is strongly continuous but not continuous in norm, which is what I presume the OP has in mind.

Comment: @Ruy Right, I missed that. If it is norm continuous my candidate would be  ${1\over t_0}\log U_{t_0} $ if $\|U_{t_0}-I\|<1,$ $t_0\neq 0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc.  This doesn't work even when $A=\mathbb C$.  Consider $U(t)=e^{itx}$, and $t_0=2k\pi/x$.

Comment: @Ruy I was not precise. I consider  $t_0$ such that  $\|U_t-I\|<1$ for $0<t\le t_0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\ex[1]{\exp\left(#1\right)}$

The answer is yes.  Rather than proving that $U$ is differentiable, we will construct $x$ explicitly.

Denoting by $S$ the "square" map on $A$,  that is,
$$
  S(a)=a^2, \quad (a\in  A),
  $$
notice that the differential of $S$ at 1 is the map
$$
  DS_1(h)=2h, \quad\forall h\in  A,
  $$
hence an invertible map.
Using the Inverse Function Theorem we then have that there exists a neighborhood $V$ of 1 restricted to which, $S$ is
injective.

Next consider the exponential map
$$
  \exp:A\to A,
  $$
and
observe that its differential at zero is the identity map so, again by the Inverse Function Theorem there are open
neighborhoods $Y\ni 0$ and $Z\ni 1$, such that $\exp$ maps $Y$  homeomorphically onto $Z$.

By shrinking both $Y$ and $Z$, we may suppose that $Y=B_r(0)$, namely the open ball centered at zero, for some
radius $r>0$, and that $Z\subseteq V$.

Schematically
$$
  \exp: B_r(0)\to Z\subseteq V.
  $$
Using that $U$ is **norm** continuous,  pick  $\delta >0$ such that
$$
  |t|<\delta  \ \Rightarrow \ U(t)\in  Z.
  $$
For each nonzero
$t$ with $|t|<\delta $, set
$$
  y(t)=(\exp|_Z)^{-1}\big (U(t)\big ),
  $$
so that $y(t)\in  B_r(0)$,
$\ex{y(t)}=U(t)$, and we claim that
$$
  \ex{y(t)/2} = U(t/2). \qquad (*)
  $$
To see this, notice that
$$
  \ex{y(t)/2}^2 = \ex{2y(t)/2} = \ex{y(t)} = U(t)=
 U(t/2)^2,
  $$
so,
to conclude the proof of $(*)$, it is enough to check that both   $\ex{y(t)/2}$ and  $U(t/2)$ lie in $V$, where the square map $S$ is
injective. Indeed,  notice that $y(t)\in  B_r(0)$, so
$$
  y(t)/2\in  B_r(0) \ \Rightarrow \ex{y(t)/2}\in  Z\subseteq V.
  $$
Also $U(t/2) \in V$, because
$$
  |t/2| < \delta  \ \Rightarrow \  U(t/2) \in  Z\subseteq V.
  $$

As a consequence of $(*)$ we have that
$$
  \ex{y(t)/2} = U(t/2) = \ex{y(t/2)}.
  $$
Moreover,  since both   $y(t)/2$ and $y(t/2)$ lie in $B_r(0)$, where the exponential is injective,  we deduce that
$$
  y(t)/2=y(t/2),
  $$
and   by induction  we get that
$$
  y(t)/{2^n}=y(t/{2^n}),\quad \forall n\geq 0.
  $$

Choosing any integers  $n$ and $p$, with $n\geq 0$, and  $|p|<2^n$, we claim that
$$
  py(t)/{2^n}=y(pt/{2^n}).
  $$
To prove this notice that the two terms above lie in $B_r(0)$, so it is enough to show that $\exp$ takes on the same
values on them.  In fact
$$
  \ex{py(t)/{2^n}} =
  \ex{py(t/2^n)} =
  \ex{y(t/2^n)}^p =
  $$$$=
  U(t/2^n)^p =
  U(pt/2^n) =
  \ex{y(pt/2^n)}.
  $$
This shows that
$
  ry(t)=y(rt),
  $
for every diadic rational $r$ with $|r|<1$, and since $y$ is continuous, the same holds for every real number $r$,
with $|r|\leq 1$.

Choosing any $t_0$ with $|t_0|<\delta $, and setting $x=y(t_0)/t_0$, we then claim that
$U(s) = \ex{sx}$, for every real $s$.  To prove this, find an integer number $p$ large enough so that $t:=s/p$
satisfies $|t|<|t_0|$,  and then
$$
  U(s) = U(pt)=U(t)^p = $$$$ =
  \ex{y(t)}^p =
  \ex{y((t/t_0)t_0)}^p = $$$$ =
  \ex{(t/t_0)y(t_0)}^p =
  \ex{tx}^p = $$$$ =
  \ex{ptx} =   \ex{sx}.  \qquad\text{QED}
  $$

Answer (score 2):

For an element $T$ of a unital Banach algebra, such that $\sigma(T)\subset \mathcal{C}\setminus (-\infty, 0]$ we can define $\log (T)$ by the analytic functional calculus. For $T=I+V$ and $\|V\|<1$  we have a power series representation of $\log(T)$ as
$$\log(T)=\log(I+V)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^{k+1}\over k} V^k$$

Assume two elements $T=I+V,\,S=I+U$ are commuting and $$\|V\|\le {1\over 4},\quad \|U\|\le {1\over 4}$$
Then $TS=I+(V+U+VU)$ and $$\|V+U+VU\|\le {7\over 16}$$
Therefore all three elements $\log(I+V),\ \log(I+U)$ and $\log((I+V)(I+U))$ can be represented by the absolutely convergent power series.

We are going to show that
$$\log(TS)=\log(T)+\log (S)\qquad (*)$$
The formula  $(*)$ takes the form
$$\log[(I+V)(I+U)]=\log(I+V)+\log(I+U) \quad (**)$$
For $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|<{1\over 4}$ and $|w|<{1\over 4}$ we have $$\log((1+z)(1+w))=\log(1+z)+\log(1+w)$$  hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^{k+1}\over k} (z+w+zw)^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^{k+1}\over k} z^k+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^{k+1}\over k} w^k
$$
The  series on RHS are absolutely convergent. Also the series on LHS is absolutely convergent as
$$|z+w+zw|\le |z|+|w|+|z|\,|w|\le {7\over 16}$$
Therefore both sides are of the form
$$\sum_{k,l=1}^\infty a_{k,l}z^kw^l$$ and the double series is absolutely convergent. The coeefficients $a_{k,l}$ are uniquely determined. Thus we may substitute $z:=V$ and $w:=U$ to get
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^{k+1}\over k} (V+U+VU)^k=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^{k+1}\over k} V^k+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {(-1)^{k+1}\over k} U^k
$$ which gives $(**)$.

Let $$B=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\,:\,|z-1|\le {1\over 4}$$
By continuity of the semigroup, there exists $t_0>0$ such that
$$\|U_t-I\|\le {1\over 4},\qquad 0<t\le t_0$$
Define
$$A={1\over t_0}\log U_{t_0}$$
For $1\le k\le n$ we have ${kt_0\over n} \le t_0.$  By $(*)$ we get
$$t_0A=\log U_{t_0}=\log U_{t_0/n}^n=n\log U_{t_0/n} $$
Hence $$ \log U_{t_0/n}={t_0\over n}A$$
Next   for $1\le k\le n$  we get (again by applying  $(*)$)
$$\log U_{kt_0/n}=\log( U_{t_0/n}^k) =k\log U_{t_0/n}={k\over n}\log U_{t_0}$$
By continuity of $(0,t_0]\ni t\mapsto U_t$ and of $\log$ (for example by the power series representation) we obtain that
$$\log U_{at_0}=a\log U_{t_0}=at_0A,\qquad 0<a\le 1$$
which implies
$$\log U_t=tA,\qquad 0<t\le t_0\qquad (**)$$
Thus
$$ U_t=e^{tA},\qquad 0<t\le t_0\qquad \quad(***)$$
By the group property the identity extends to the whole line.

**Remark** The implication $(**)\implies (***)$ is based on the following. Let $U$ be  an element of a unital Banach algebra and $f$ be an analytic function in the open neighborhood of $\sigma(U).$ Then for any entire function $g$ we have
$$g(f(U))=(g\circ f)(U)\quad\  (****)$$ In our case $U=U_t,$ $f(z)=\log z$ and $g(w)=e^w.$ Thus $$(g\circ f)(z)=z,\qquad e^{\log U_t}=(g\circ f)(U_t)=U_t$$

The formula $(****)$ can be proved straightforward. Let $g(z)=\sum g_nz^n.$ Then $$g(f(U))=\sum g_n f(U)^n =\sum g_n f^n(U)=\left (\sum g_n f^n\right )(U)=(g\circ f)(U)$$

Comment: Nice.  The biggest problem I faced in my proof was to justify the passage $\log(T^n)=n\log(T)$, for $\|T-1\|<1$. Do you have a quick reason for this?

Comment: @Ruy Thanks. I have no idea how to show that quickly, basing on $\|I-T\|<1$ only. If $\|I-T\|< 2^{-n}$ then $\|I-T^k\|<1$  for $1\le k\le n$  and then the formula follows.

Comment: @Ruy I see a problem how to define $\log(T^{6})$ if $\|I-T\|<1.$ Let $S$ be a shift operator whose spectrum coincides with the closed unit disc. Take $T=I+{1\over \sqrt{3}}S.$ Then $$\sigma(T^{6})=\left \{\left (1+{z\over \sqrt{3}}\right )^{6}\,:\, |z|\le 1\right\}$$ I have impression that $\sigma(T^{6})$ contains a closed curve around $0.$ For example the angles of $1\pm {i\over \sqrt{3}}$ are equal $\pm {\pi\over 6}.$ The line connecting  these two points, after raising to the power $6,$ will produce a closed curve around $0$ which is contained in $\sigma(T^6).$

Comment: Very interesting example!  But now I am a bit lost: how do you justify the statement in your answer that says $$\log U_{t_0/n}^n=n\log U_{t_0/n} .$$
Doesn't this require knowing that 
$\|I-U_{t_0/n}\|<2^{-n}$ ?

Comment: @Ruy It suffices that $\|U_t-I\|<1$ for all $0<t\le t_0$ not just for $t_0.$ I will re-edit my answer tomorrow to clarify reasonings. Thanks for analyzing the details.

Comment: @Ruy It should be clearer now. The simplest way would be to prove that $\log (UV)=\log U+\log V$ for two commuting elements such that $\|U-I\| \le {1\over 2}, $ $ \|V-I\|\le {1\over 2}$ and $\|UV-I\|\le {1\over 2},$ by applying the power series expansion of $\log z$ for $|z-1|\le {1\over 2}.$ In this way we can avoid using analytic functional calculus, where $f(U)$ is defined through integral along a curve surrounding the spectrum of $U.$   But I am too lazy to make calculations.

Comment: @Ruy Only now I got what you meant by a quick proof of the formula $\log(T^n)=n\log T$ under the assumption $\|T-I\|<1.$ If we additionally assume that $\|T^k-I\|<1$ for $1\le k\le n-1,$ the formula follows from $(*)$ in my answer. This additional assumption, when applied to $U_{t_0/n},$ is satisfied by the semigroup property of $U_t.$

Comment: Looks good to me now!  One small comment, when you first used (*) you were also implicitly using (****), with
$g(z)=\log(z)$ and $f(z)=z^n$, except that $g$ is not entire here.  However this is no big deal since you may add the
requirement that $z^n$ is also in $\mathbb C_+$ in which case you may prove (****) via the integral formula.

Comment: When I was
working on my answer I did think of a proof along these lines but I found it to messy to deal with the logarithm and
hence with path integrals and a power series with finite convergent radius and hence I chose to work with the inverse of
the exponential instead.

Comment: @Ruy I think I did not need $(****)$ when I first used $(*).$ I have simply applied:  if $g_1(z)=g_2(z)$  for $z$ in an open neighbourhood of $\sigma(T)$ then $g_1(T)=g_2(T).$

Comment: This is really a minor point but to put it in a better perspective the question is why does the function "$\log(x^n)$" applied to some element $u\in A$ coincides with the function "$\log(x)$" applied to $u^n$?

Comment: @Ruy You are right. That requires an explanation.